# WordPress RSS Feed - &#8217; instead of the apostrophe (')

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed, cdata

In my Wordpress RSS Feed : http://hellobiz.fr/feed/

Apostrophes are replaced by "’" in

I need to use the true character: '

Do you have solution please ?

Thank you !

Comment: I think `'` is not allowed in XML.

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed the problem, although it might not be the most correct/elegant solution.

In wp-includes/feed-functions.php

```
function get_the_title_rss() {
$title = get_the_title();
// $title = apply_filters('the_title', $title);
$title = apply_filters('the_title_rss', $title);
return $title;
```

Commenting out that line changed the offending "right single quotation mark" (aka ’) into the straight up and down apostrophe that apparently magpie can handle no problem.

Before I started digging in the code I was playing with the encoding, and was in for a HECK of a surprise when I changed it to UTF-16.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is in description><![CDATA... not in title. Your function is not fix ?